# How to generate valid folder names with encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

In Windows there are certain characters that are not allowed as folder names. I am trying to implement a simple program that can encrypt and rename folders. I believe I can use the old traditional form of cryptography to achieve this. Any other suggestions? Is there some other *official* way of doing this?

### **Edit:**

I have also considered using hashing, but considering I'd also like to be able to Decrypt, that won't make much sense.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: To clarify you want the same folder/file name output every time for the same folder/file name input? If so, I have a follow up question, should two folders/files in different sub directories have the same name or different names. For example should `/Foo1/Bar.exe` and `/Foo2/Bar.exe` turn in to `/Foo1/ASDF` and `/Foo2/ASDF` or should `Foo2` be `/Foo2/MNBV`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a random name that is valid for a file/folder name just use [`Path.GetRandomFilename()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx)

> The GetRandomFileName method returns a cryptographically strong, random string that can be used as either a folder name or a file name.

The function returns a string that has 8 random alphanumeric characters, a period, then 3 random alphanumeric characters.

**EDIT:** If what you want is to encrypt the filename, not generate a random filename you could do a few options.

1. Still use the random filename and store the original name as part of some encrypted header information inside the file itself (just encrypt the length of the name, the name, then all the bytes of the original file, when you decrypt you read out the original name and use that when you restore the file.
2. Encrypt the name of the file itself then use [`Convert.ToBase64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) on the encrypted byte array, all the characters `ToBase64` outputs in its string are valid to use in a filename.